# C++ how to change the same range of characters in the console

Tags: c++, console

I need to know how should I change the outputted characters (to a console).
Regularly, we would do this:

```
cout << "Hello World!" << endl;
```

And if after that we add this line:

```
cout << "Second Hello World" << endl;
```

We get this result(which in no way is what I want):

```
Hello World!
Second Hello World
```

Now, I want to change the same range of characters which already have been inserted, how should I do this? Something like a process_range or a loading_range in the console, similar to Linux Console when you want to install a package:

```
Package: PHP5.6 [===>            ] 23%
```

Can anyone help? Or is it complex? Thanks

Comment: You might want to use ncurses.

Comment: I appreciate if you elaborate more...

Comment: ncurses is a library that allows you to output escape characters that manipulate the terminal in more elaborate ways than you can do by simply sending characters to stdout.  It is how programs like less, vi, and emacs were implemented.

Comment: Search for ncurse. It will contain some function to set cursor at a given position, and cross-platform.. Otherwise, on Win32 API, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686025%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: There isn't a portable mechanism in vanilla C++ to do this because it depends on what console/terminal you're using. It requires outputting special escape codes, and the Windows Command Prompt uses different escape codes than Linux terminals do, for example. A library such as ncurses can abstract this for you, if you don't mind introducing a new dependency.